# Python Deep Learning can't save trained data with pickle module

Tags: python, machine-learning

I would like to save the trained data but keep getting the error message saying:
`[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'digits.pkl'`.

How can I save it as 'digits.pkl'? I was writing the code on jupyter notebook through Visual Studio.

```python
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# データを読み込む --- (*1)
digits = datasets.load_digits()
x = digits.images
y = digits.target
x = x.reshape((-1, 64)) # 二次元配列を一次元配列に変換 --- (*2)

# データを学習用とテスト用に分割する --- (*3)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

# データを学習 --- (*4)
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

# 予測して精度を確認する --- (*5)
y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

import pickle
with open("digits.pkl", "wb") as fp:
    pickle.dump(clf, fp)
```

Error message:

```txt
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/_x/q412fn8n5zxghsk407x6k_r40000gn/T/ipykernel_50260/1718269470.py in <module>
     22 
     23 import pickle
---> 24 with open("digits.pkl", "wb") as fp:
     25     pickle.dump(clf, fp)

OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'digits.pkl'
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to save the trained model `clf` as opposed to the training data, What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I believe you do not have write permissions on the directory that you're at. Could you check your permissions?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The permissions are fine I believe. To be honest, I'm just following the book and don't know what exactly I'm doing here. I just want to save trained digit recognition data as "digits.pkl" so I can use it for another program. The book says that was how I could save the trained data and can be used for different programs.

Comment: I also believe what you're trying to do is to save the model for inference on new datasets / separate programs, so the code above makes sense. I've looked up issues with such `OSError` as you've described, and they all seem to suggest that you might be writing to a read-only directory. If you're on linux, can you do a `ls -lh` on the directory to check your permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/fstab` or run `findmnt` to see how that directory is mounted - if there's "ro" in the mount options, it means you can't write to it, even if `ls -l` shows a write permission.

Are you able to create files in that directory manually?
If you simply had no permission, the error would probably say that ([Errno 13] Permission denied) instead of [Errno 30] Read-only file system.